# Switch scrolling direction with shortkey

Tags: scroll, autohotkey

I currently have an AHK script which switches the scrolling direction of my mouse.

```
WheelUp::
Send {WheelDown}
Return

WheelDown::
Send {WheelUp}
Return
```

My colleagues don't like this and use my computer sometimes.

How can I assign a shortkey to switch the scrolling direction?

**What I want:**
When I press <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> the scrolling direction is changed, when I pres <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> again, the scrolling direction is changed back.

So basically the scrolling direction can be changed when pressing <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>

Is that possible with AHK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can modify your hotkeys to have more code.

You will have to use if statements and variables.

Example:

```
global direction := 1

^s::    ; ctrl + s will launch this code you can modify this to win + z
    direction := Mod( direction + 1 , 2 ) ; alternates values of direction between 1 and 0
return

WheelUp::
    if(direction)
        Send {WheelDown}
    else
        Send {WheelUp}
Return

; and reverse for wheeldown
```

Comment: @JoeDF how about a direction := abs(-direction+1)? :)